# Trying to use "useFontCache: false" in Mathjax-node

Tags: node.js, svg, mathjax

I try to use "useFontCache: false" in [MathJax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node). Here is my example code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node");

mjAPI.config({MathJax: {SVG: {font: "TeX"}}});
mjAPI.start();

mjAPI.typeset({
  math: "\sin^2+\cos^2=1",
  format: ("TeX"),
  svg:true,
  useFontCache: false,
  ex: 6, width: 100,
}, function (data) {
  if (!data.errors) {console.log(data.svg)}
});
```

and the generated output still uses < use> tags:

```
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="15.722ex" height="2.843ex" style="vertical-align: -0.505ex;" viewBox="0 -1006.6 6769.3 1223.9" role="img" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-labelledby="MathJax-SVG-1-Title">
<title id="MathJax-SVG-1-Title">sin^2+cos^2=1</title>
<defs aria-hidden="true">
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-73" d="M131 289Q131 321 147 354T203 415T300 442Q362 442 390 415T419 355Q419 323 402 308T364 292Q351 292 340 300T328 326Q328 342 337 354T354 372T367 378Q368 378 368 379Q368 382 361 388T336 399T297 405Q249 405 227 379T204 326Q204 301 223 291T278 274T330 259Q396 230 396 163Q396 135 385 107T352 51T289 7T195 -10Q118 -10 86 19T53 87Q53 126 74 143T118 160Q133 160 146 151T160 120Q160 94 142 76T111 58Q109 57 108 57T107 55Q108 52 115 47T146 34T201 27Q237 27 263 38T301 66T318 97T323 122Q323 150 302 164T254 181T195 196T148 231Q131 256 131 289Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-69" d="M184 600Q184 624 203 642T247 661Q265 661 277 649T290 619Q290 596 270 577T226 557Q211 557 198 567T184 600ZM21 287Q21 295 30 318T54 369T98 420T158 442Q197 442 223 419T250 357Q250 340 236 301T196 196T154 83Q149 61 149 51Q149 26 166 26Q175 26 185 29T208 43T235 78T260 137Q263 149 265 151T282 153Q302 153 302 143Q302 135 293 112T268 61T223 11T161 -11Q129 -11 102 10T74 74Q74 91 79 106T122 220Q160 321 166 341T173 380Q173 404 156 404H154Q124 404 99 371T61 287Q60 286 59 284T58 281T56 279T53 278T49 278T41 278H27Q21 284 21 287Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-6E" d="M21 287Q22 293 24 303T36 341T56 388T89 425T135 442Q171 442 195 424T225 390T231 369Q231 367 232 367L243 378Q304 442 382 442Q436 442 469 415T503 336T465 179T427 52Q427 26 444 26Q450 26 453 27Q482 32 505 65T540 145Q542 153 560 153Q580 153 580 145Q580 144 576 130Q568 101 554 73T508 17T439 -10Q392 -10 371 17T350 73Q350 92 386 193T423 345Q423 404 379 404H374Q288 404 229 303L222 291L189 157Q156 26 151 16Q138 -11 108 -11Q95 -11 87 -5T76 7T74 17Q74 30 112 180T152 343Q153 348 153 366Q153 405 129 405Q91 405 66 305Q60 285 60 284Q58 278 41 278H27Q21 284 21 287Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-32" d="M109 429Q82 429 66 447T50 491Q50 562 103 614T235 666Q326 666 387 610T449 465Q449 422 429 383T381 315T301 241Q265 210 201 149L142 93L218 92Q375 92 385 97Q392 99 409 186V189H449V186Q448 183 436 95T421 3V0H50V19V31Q50 38 56 46T86 81Q115 113 136 137Q145 147 170 174T204 211T233 244T261 278T284 308T305 340T320 369T333 401T340 431T343 464Q343 527 309 573T212 619Q179 619 154 602T119 569T109 550Q109 549 114 549Q132 549 151 535T170 489Q170 464 154 447T109 429Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-2B" d="M56 237T56 250T70 270H369V420L370 570Q380 583 389 583Q402 583 409 568V270H707Q722 262 722 250T707 230H409V-68Q401 -82 391 -82H389H387Q375 -82 369 -68V230H70Q56 237 56 250Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-63" d="M34 159Q34 268 120 355T306 442Q362 442 394 418T427 355Q427 326 408 306T360 285Q341 285 330 295T319 325T330 359T352 380T366 386H367Q367 388 361 392T340 400T306 404Q276 404 249 390Q228 381 206 359Q162 315 142 235T121 119Q121 73 147 50Q169 26 205 26H209Q321 26 394 111Q403 121 406 121Q410 121 419 112T429 98T420 83T391 55T346 25T282 0T202 -11Q127 -11 81 37T34 159Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMATHI-6F" d="M201 -11Q126 -11 80 38T34 156Q34 221 64 279T146 380Q222 441 301 441Q333 441 341 440Q354 437 367 433T402 417T438 387T464 338T476 268Q476 161 390 75T201 -11ZM121 120Q121 70 147 48T206 26Q250 26 289 58T351 142Q360 163 374 216T388 308Q388 352 370 375Q346 405 306 405Q243 405 195 347Q158 303 140 230T121 120Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-3D" d="M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Z"></path>
<path stroke-width="1" id="E1-MJMAIN-31" d="M213 578L200 573Q186 568 160 563T102 556H83V602H102Q149 604 189 617T245 641T273 663Q275 666 285 666Q294 666 302 660V361L303 61Q310 54 315 52T339 48T401 46H427V0H416Q395 3 257 3Q121 3 100 0H88V46H114Q136 46 152 46T177 47T193 50T201 52T207 57T213 61V578Z"></path>
</defs>
<g stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)" aria-hidden="true">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-73" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-69" x="469" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(815,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-6E" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-32" x="849" y="583"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-2B" x="2091" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-63" x="3092" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-6F" x="3525" y="0"></use>
<g transform="translate(4011,0)">
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMATHI-73" x="0" y="0"></use>
 <use transform="scale(0.707)" xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-32" x="663" y="583"></use>
</g>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-3D" x="5212" y="0"></use>
 <use xlink:href="#E1-MJMAIN-31" x="6268" y="0"></use>
</g>
</svg>
```

I tried editing the MathJax SVG config, instead of the typeset, but still no change. Anybody know, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are you expecting instead of the <use> tags?

Comment: I'm expecting just paths, like the MathJax Documentation (http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/output-processors/SVG.html) suggest: This controls whether the SVG output uses <use> elements to re-use font paths rather than repeat paths every time.

Comment: It looks like a bug. I've filed https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/issues/392.

Comment: Thank you, Peter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a regression](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/issues/392) in the v2.0.0 (and 2.0.1) releases; v1.3.0 works as expected and a bug fix is ready for the next release.